# How to import 2,3 object from another file in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am beginner to ReactJS, Currently I am using `styled-component` for style some module. Actually I created 2 files in one folder. One is `style.js` where I am making 2,3 object and now I want to export these 3 object to my another file which name is `2nd.js` but it not working for me Could you please help me How I can import `style.js` object to my file .

**Style.js Code**

```
  import styled from 'styled-components';

  export const SubText = styled.div`
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  width: 330px;
  color: #012653;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: 440;
`;
export const GeneralText = styled.div`
  color: red;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 266px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #012653;
`;
export const ButtonWrapper = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 26px;
`;
```

**2nd.js Code**

```
    import Style from './Style';

<GeneralText>This is dummy text </GeneralText>
```

Comment: You need to use name import something like this {SubText,ButtonWrapper, GeneralText  }

Comment: @CodeManiac I have already tried but in meantime they give me error ...  `GeneralText is not defined`

Comment: @CodeManiac Thank you solved :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by:-

```
import {SubText, GeneralText, ButtonWrapper} from './style'
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually,there are many ways to solve this:

```
import * as Style from './style'
```

Or the above answers says:

```
import {SubText, GeneralText, ButtonWrapper} from './style'
```